# Inconsistencies in using <% break if %> statements causing never ending loops *Fixed

Tags: ruby

I have written two functions where in one of the the `break if array.length == num` statements works, while the other does not. Here are the methods and their tests, starting with the working:

```js
def primes(n)
  ret = []

  return [] if n < 1

  for num in 2..+1.0/0.0
    ret << num if prime?(num)

    break if ret.count == n
  end

  ret
end

def prime?(num)
  (1..num).select {|x| num % x == 0}.count == 2
end

puts "\nPrimes:\n" + "*" * 15 + "\n"
puts primes(0) == []
puts primes(1) == [2]
puts primes(2) == [2,3]
puts primes(6) == [2,3,5,7,11,13]
```

Comment: Check  your assumptions. Is `2` prime? If so, and you add it to `ret`, will `ret.count` ever be `0`? The inconsistency isn't in the `break` syntax/calculation, it's that you have no endgame under some circumstances.

Comment: I see now. I added a <% return [] if n < 1 %> statement. Thanks!

Comment: What might be a better way to return the first N values? Thanks Again!

Comment: There are always lazy sequences, but I suspect that's not what you're looking for. `each_with_object` would be marginally cleaner (instead of creating the array explicitly and returning it at the end).